# How to know the version of pip itself

Tags: python, pip

Which shell command gives me the actual version of `pip` I am using?

`pip` gives with `pip show` all version of modules that are installed but excludes itself.

Comment: @doniyor: and `pip -h` would have told you about the option..

Comment: The reason this is upvoted so much is because the `-version` flag is found between the `--isolated` flag and `--proxy` flags, that is where the user scans, and the eyes start glazing over.  It's a bad design to put extremely common command hidden between stuff that looks like the developer of pip accidentally piped random internet jargon to screen and then thought: "oh yeah, now I'll talk about basic usage".  This is a common theme in python, where python is less a pre-packaged system and more a trashbag of tools dumped on the floor.

Comment: Doing `python.exe -m pip show pip` works as of now with pip-20.1.1 and Python 3.7.5 though.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You can do this:

```
pip -V
```

or:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: For windows users: python -m pip --version

Comment: Both `pip -V` and `pip --version` work for me on Win10

Comment: pip3 --version for  python3

Comment: Just to add that if the above doesn't work, 
try pip3 -V FOR Python 3

Comment: A quiz question 's answer on PythonInstitute-Edube platform says that `pip --version` , `pip -version`, `pip version`  can be used to determine pip version.I checked the codes on my windows pc' s cmd, and then  only `pip --version` worked. Is the answer false ? Or am I missing anything else?

Comment: Both of these give me `ImportError: cannot import name 'FormatControl'` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67464298/how-to-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-formatcontrol-for-pip#comment132512749_68943800). Simply running `pip` does too. But I do have `pip`: ` load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip3.6')()` and `which pip` gives me `/usr/bin/pip`

Answer (score 21):

Just for completeness:

`pip -V`

`pip --version`

`pip list` and inside the list you'll find also pip with its version.

Answer (score 18):

For windows just type:

```
python -m pip --version
```

Answer (score 16):

For windows:

```
import pip

help(pip)
```

shows the version at the end of the help file.

Comment: Within a script (presumably on any platform) you can do:

import pip;
pip.__version__

(But I'm not sure that you *should*)

Comment: import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Answer (score 11):

Any of the following should work

```
pip --version
# pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

or

```
pip -V       
# pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

or

```
pip3 -V      
# pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Answer (score 7):

check two things

```
pip2 --version
```

and

```
pip3 --version
```

because the default pip may be anyone of this so it is always better to check both.

Answer (score 7):

Many people use both 2.X and 3.X python. You can use `pip -V` to show default pip version.
If you have many python versions, and you want to install some packages through different pip, I advise this way:

```
sudo python2.X -m pip install some-package==0.16
```

Answer (score 7):

Start Python and type `import pip` `pip.__version__` which works for all python packages.

Answer (score 6):

On RHEL "pip -V" works :

```
$ pip -V
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, open a command prompt After type a bellow commands.

check a version itself Easily :

**Form Windows:**

> pip installation :

```
pip install pip
```

> pip Version check:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: Come on. If you *have* pip, you don't need to install it.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows machine go to command prompt and type.

```
pip -V
```

Comment: Does not work. "Traceback (most recent call last): and bla bla.."

Answer (score 3):

```
`pip -v` or `pip --v`
```

However note, if you are using macos catelina which has the zsh (z shell) it might give you a whole bunch of things, so the best option is to try install the version or start as `-- pip3`

Answer (score 1):

py -m pip --version

This worked for python version 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone knows this, but you can actually import pip since its a package:

```py
from pip import __version__
print(__version__)
```

Answer (score -1):

`pip3 --version`

-If you using python 3.12.1 or any version above 3 of python in macOS you need to use above command to check pip version.

Comment: This is already given in the [older answer from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634109/2745495)