# How do you check the pip version for python 3.8.3?

Tags: pip, pygame, python-3.8

I am a windows 10 user and I uninstalled python 3.8.3 and then reinstalled it for the ultimate goal of downloading pygame on my computer (which I need pip for). When I tried using the command prompt to check what version of pip I currently have, it says that I have:

No Python at 'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe'

I have already added Python to my path variable but I do not know what to do next. Please help!

Comment: Setup your environment variable

Comment: Move your python installation to that location?

Comment: This Question has been answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378344/how-to-know-the-version-of-pip-itself

Comment: prince09, I typed pip --version in cmd but the 'No Python at... ' message appeared. Also, what exactly is an environment variable? And how do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered at [How to know the version of pip itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378344/how-to-know-the-version-of-pip-itself). but you can do the following in the Command Prompt:
First type python in the command prompt and then hit enter.

```
import pip
pip.__version__
```

To add python directory to path
At the command prompt − type `path %path%;C:\Python` and press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to find a solution (somewhat). I downloaded an older version of python, moved my python installation folder to C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37, and installed pygame using pip. Thank you all!